# Does the same-origin-policy prevent JavaScript on a page from accessing the contents of cross-domain loaded resources like <img> and <script>?

Tags: javascript, html, same-origin-policy

According to PortSwigger's [description](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cors/same-origin-policy) of the same-origin-policy (see below), JavaScript on a page cannot read the contents of cross-domain loaded resources, like `<img>`, `<video>`, and `<script>`, on that page.

However, answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650663/same-origin-policy-in-external-js-file) states that:

> when mysite.com is openning a tag, that script runs in the scope of
>   the current page.

or phrased differently:

> The origin of a script is where it's included.

So, what exactly does PortSwigger mean? If JavaScript code on a page cannot read the contents of `<script>`s, then how can jQuery and other JavaScript frameworks loaded from CDNs by used in pages?

**How is the same-origin policy implemented?** (PortSwigger)

The same-origin policy generally controls the access that JavaScript code has to content that is loaded cross-domain. Cross-origin loading of page resources is generally permitted. For example, the SOP allows embedding of images via the `<img>` tag, media via the `<video>` tag and JavaScript includes with the `<script>` tag. However, while these external resources can be loaded by the page, any JavaScript on the page won't be able to read the contents of these resources.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image as an example of JS accessing images.

Comment: @Teemu - thanks, I've read your page. I see that e.g. `<img>` can only be consumed by JavaScript if `crossorigin` is set. Will you elaborate? Is this a special case? Indeed, external scripts (`<scripts src="...">`) run with origin the page it's included?

Comment: That's pretty much it. I cannot explain it clearer than the guys has already explained it at MDN. And yes, a script loaded from a third-party server runs under your domain, just like you'd had loaded it from your own server, it can't even access the server where it came from, unless the CORS is set on that server. An exception to this is, that you can't access the text property of the cross-domain script element, that would be accessing the actual content, just like accessing a tainted canvas.

Answer (score 1):

**when mysite.com is opening a tag, that script runs in the scope of the current page** - this statement means that when the `yoursite.com/new.js` is referenced from `mysite.com`, the content of `new.js` will **not** be treated as external to `mysite.com`.

`new.js` will run in the scope of current page(i.e., `mysite.com`) **as if** the `new.js` is loaded from `mysite.com`(or any other site for that matter).

The statement from PortSwigger explains that browser is able to reference a remote image or video via the HTML tags, but the javascript (regardless if loaded from mysite.com or yoursite.com) will **not** be able to access the remote images/video.

Comment: Thank you. Where can I see all of this formalized? I think there are many edge cases or special cases.

Comment: here is a good read [link](https://www.netsparker.com/whitepaper-same-origin-policy/)

Comment: Is there no formal specification of the same-origin-policy, like a RFC?

Comment: SOP is a security concept, not a protocol restriction. There are even minor differences in the way each browser implements this concept. Wiki page says _All modern browsers implement **some form of** the same-origin policy as it is an important security cornerstone.[7] **The policies are not required to match an exact specification**_